# Enable php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed wordpress using bitnami. Please let me know how to enable php in wordpress

However when i write a simple php code in a post or page like :

```
<?php
  echo " hello ";
?>
```

the page does not displays the above code as it is and not as what php is supposed to dispay.

Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

There are several plugins that will let you do this, depending on where you want to use them:

[Allow PHP in Posts and Pages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/)

[PHP Code for Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-for-posts/)

[PHP Code Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/)

Comment: These were found by a pretty simple Google search, by the way.